# Understanding $k$-axis of band structure

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals, electronic-band-theory

So right now im reading about TMDC's and there was this picture

[image]

And I dont understand the x axis. There it only says k vector. But what is it exactly ? Is it real $\vec{k}$ or $|\vec{k}|$ or $k_y$ or $k_y$ or $k_z$ ? I mean it could have been that they just show the energies at the marked points($\Gamma$,$\Sigma$,...) but there are also energies between these marked points. And I dont get how the graph can be calculated in between the marked points and where the corresponding k vectors would be in the left picture.

Comment: Those are crystal momentum vectors along the different indicated directions within the Brillouin zone. The momentum vectors can assume any value between the zone center and the zone edge.

Comment: What  is  TMDC???